# AlamofireObjectMapper integration issue with Xcode 7.2.1 using cocoapod

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am integrating AlamofireObjetMapper in my project using cocoapods with Xcode 7.2.1
 After pod file is being installed, whenever I'm opening the .xcworkspace and trying to build it shows me the errors attached in the image.

Please help me which version of AlamofireObjetMapper should I use with Xcode 7.2.1.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of `AlamofireObjetMapper` is not compatible with Xcode 7.2.1 because it's do not support Swift 2.2+ You have to update Xcode to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for answering.